# How to configure squid proxy to allow only 1 http request in a connection?

Tags: http, connection, reusability, squid

Squid by default establishes 1 or more connections to server and also reuses the connections for multiple http requests. I would like to limit the number of http request sent from squid to server to 1 for each connection. i.e. Do not re-use connections. Is it possible?